# Error: already exists.(stg_e_filealreadyexists) when using IMapDocument.Open method?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I got the error: already exists.(stg_e_filealreadyexists) when using the method IMapDocument.Open() as below codes:

```
if (File.Exists (strDirectory + "\\temp.mxd"))
    File.Delete(strDirectory + "\\temp.mxd");
System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(strDirectory + "\\temp.mxd", FileMode.Create);
oFileStream.Write(MyImage, 0, MyImage.Length);
IMapDocument mapDoc = new MapDocumentClass();
mapDoc.Open(strDirectory + "\\temp.mxd"); // Throw exception
```

Do you know why and how to fix this error ?